# Can't receive a push notification from pushwoosh.com

Tags: android, push, android-notifications

**1.** I download: [Sample Project](https://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android/native-android-sdk-integration/) from this link

**2.** Import in my eclipce this project
pushwoosh-sdk-samples-master.zip\pushwoosh-sdk-samples-master\Native\Android\

**3.** 
On website is info that

> PW_APPID – Pushwoosh Application ID

(MY: Application Code: **8CD4F-FXXXX**)

> PW_PROJECT_ID – Project Number you receive from Google GCM

(MY: Project ID: **eternal-psyche-777** Project Number: **520518000000**)

So i replace this info in manifest to mine

```
meta-data
    android:name="PW_APPID"
    android:value="8CD4F-FXXXX" 
meta-data
    android:name="PW_PROJECT_ID"
    android:value="520518000000"
```

**4.** Also I add Google Cloud Messaging API Key to Application on pushwoosh.com

But after sending a push notification, nothing happens...What is wrong?

**UPDATED:**
Found 
where PW_APPID – Pushwoosh Application ID, PW_PROJECT_ID – Project Number you receive from Google GCM, Project ID is a number but make sure you prefix it with **the letter “A”**

but I still can't receive a push-notification...

Comment: Do you see the subscriber in the Pushwoosh Control Panel? Can you provide logs from the device?